# Version is not updating in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a Maven plugin (`com.helloworld.plugin`) which reads the version from `pom.xml` in another Maven project. I have a Java class `HelloWorld` for that purpose which looks like this -

```
package com.helloworld.plugin.com.helloworld.plugin;

import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.LifecyclePhase;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;

@Mojo(name = "say-helloworld",defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class HelloWorld extends AbstractMojo{

    @Component
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        getLog().info("Hello World!!");

        String version = project.getVersion();
        String release = version;

        getLog().info(version);

        if(version.indexOf("-SNAPSHOT")>1) {
        release = version.substring(0, version.indexOf("-SNAPSHOT"));

        }

        //project.getProperties().setProperty("newVersion", release );
        project.setVersion(release );
        getLog().info("SNAPSHOT FOUND :: " + project.getVersion());
    }
}
```

I have another Maven project in which I am using this plugin. The `pom.xml` for that project looks like this -

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestJava</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestJava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.helloworld.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.helloworld.plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>say-helloworld</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, when I am executing this `mvn package` on the second project, I get the output like this:

```
[INFO] --- com.helloworld.plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:say-helloworld (default) @ TestJava ---
[INFO] Hello World!!
[INFO] 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] SNAPSHOT FOUND :: 1.0.0
```

It looks like the version in pom.xml should have been updated to 2.0.0 by now.
But, when I refresh the pom.xml and open it again, I see that the version is not changed. It is still 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

I tried both the methods:

```
project.getProperties().setProperty("newVersion", release);
```

and

```
project.setVersion(release);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!!

Note:
1. I can't use release plugin as I am not using any SCM.
2. I tried using versions:set . but, it works only for hard coded value of version. So, I need to do it by using another maven plugin.

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to set new version number using another plugin which I am trying to create.

Comment: you said that you couldn't use `mvn versions:set` because it used a hardcoded version value, but isn't `project.setVersion("2.0.0");` using a hardcoded version value? It seems to me that there is no way of getting around a hardcoded value and you would be better off using `mvn versions:set`. If you would like to automate a deployment process just write a bash script and change the version number before each run.

Comment: I have used here 2.0.0, but my target is to read the version from the current pom.xml(which I am able to do), and do some modifications on that. Then change the currecnt data with that value. I am changing the code, to represent the actual scenario.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) which can upgrade/change versions inside the pom file etc.

Answer (score 0):

The operations on MavenProject change only runtime data, not the persistent pom.xml. Additionally most probably in new version even this wouldn't be possible: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html

Comment: So, the re is no way to change in pom.xml?

Comment: Not like this I believe.  You can still open the XML and do it manually, check [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) for inspiration as suggested in different thread.